# How to achieve SEO friendly urls with Wordpress and custom parameters

Tags: wordpress, url

I am having a big problem where I cannot use the Linkedin Share button.

One of the reasons is the non friendly URLs I am using.

Basically I have built a plugin for wordpress which shows me jobs.

It is working perfect show the jobs and everything but the link looks like this

```
www.recruitmentagency.com/job/?id=250
```

and I want it to look like

```
www.recruitmentagency.com/job/250
```

or

```
www.recruitmentagency.com/job/job-id/250
```

I tried to add rewrite rules to htaccess with no luck

```
RewriteRule ^job/([0-9]+)/$ job/?id=$1
RewriteRule ^job-id/([0-9]+)/$ /?id=$1
```

and none of them worked.

Any solution will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what about native wp premalinks?

Comment: How to implement them Michael??

Comment: start with this basic tutorial: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/seo-friendly-url-structure-for-wordpress/

Comment: Sorry Michael,
but that doesn't solve my problem, I am already using those permalinks but I have a custom plugin that has to generate SEO friendly URLs, I can generate them, but they are not read properly so the page doesn't show a job, it's just empty.

Comment: what is the purpose of custom plugin? You can modify permalinks structure in many ways, including own rule like /job/

Comment: Is for a recruitment agency.

It takes the jobs from the database and shows them in a variety of places. 
The problem is that I need the details page to be SEO friendly, because right now is not and it is causing Linkedin Share button to malfunction.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use the inbuilt system and it is partially working.

However I don't like the way it is doing it so.

Instead of getting the job like

```
$job_id=$_GET['id'];
```

I am getting it like

```
$job_id=wp_query->query_vars['page'];
```

when the page is load like

```
www.recruitmentagency.com/job/250
```

I can't even understand why my supposed job-id is appearing as a page, but I am using it since I need this to work.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue. after long time I have reached the below solutions:

```
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array','job_rewrite_rules_array');
    function job_rewrite_rules_array($rules){

        $job_page = get_post(123);
        $job_rules = array();
        if( is_object($job_page) ){
            $job_slug = $job_page->post_name;
            $job_rules[$job_slug.'/([^/]*)$'] = 'index.php?pagename='.$job_slug.'&jobid=$matches[1]'; 
        }
        return $job_rules + $rules;
    }
//Bind Query Var
        add_filter('query_vars','job_query_vars');
        function job_query_vars($vars){
            array_push($vars, 'jobid');
            return $vars;
    }
```

Execute job_rewrite_flush just one time

```
function job_rewrite_flush(){
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
    }
add_action('init','job_rewrite_flush');
```

Now access the param as: `$jobid= get_query_var( 'jobid', 1 )`

I think the above script work as per your requirement.

Comment: I don't know if this is the way to go. But it works like a charm!